# Run code on window unload?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I would like to know if there is a way to capture a page unload event that is supported by Android 2.1+ browsers (2.1 has to be supported)

I have tried

```
$(window).unload(function () { });
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () { });
```

Neither seem to work.

Comment: There's no need to add tags to titles, there's a tag system for that. Refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information. And everyone's thankful for help, there's no need to add that either to the question. You have a character sheet at the bottom of each question, your thanks are included right there. :-)

Comment: @Patrick I initially add the android-2.1 tag however its description states that it is used for questions related to Android 2.1 *SDK* (this is not the case). Also, I figured having "android" at the beginning of the subject would show up nice on search engines since the question title is used as the document title.

Comment: Oh, I'll remove it again in that case. Well, if you read the meta page, you'll see that search engines can pick up the tags as well. Otherwise you should work the word into the title, and not prefix it. Like, Run code on windows unload compatible with android-2.1 mobile browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using plain javascript:

```
window.onunload = function(e) {
    return alert('Are you sure you want to leave');
};
```

According to this [**source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) its device compatible.

However they advise to use `addEventListener` with the `unload` event:

```
 window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
        alert('Are you sure you want to leave');
  });
```

Comment: I just tested both, `window.onunload` does work however the `window.addEventListener` does not. Thank you for your help :)